# PHP + OpCache Clear - should you clear this?

Tags: php, opcache

We have a webserver running PHP with OpCache and different pools but they end up getting full. Is it the responsibility of us developers to clear the OpCache or can we just let it run full and invalidate itself?

Sometimes when we deploy multiple sites at once (and clear the opcache for those sites) the server becomes unstable. I could not really find what the best practice is so I hope to gain some feedback here.

Comment: hope this helps https://serverfault.com/questions/698064/php-opcache-100-hits-100-used-memory

Comment: Thanks @Adi that is an informative post (it helped me understand opcache a little better) :-) but I am still wondering if its true it should be cleared every once in awhile.

Comment: could you please specify your OS (win or not) and list `opcache.*` values from your `php.ini` files?